# Cumsum in R for vector

Tags: r, dataframe, cumsum

How can I use cumsum to return the index when a threshold is crossed?

```
v <- c(1,5,7,9,10,14,16,17)
Threshold <- 10
```

The function would return 3 as the cumulative sum would just be larger than 10, which provides the e index 3 as result.

Answer (score 6):

We could use `which`

```
 which(cumsum(v)>Threshold)[1]
 #[1] 3
```

Or `which.max`

```
 which.max(cumsum(v)>Threshold)
 #[1] 3
```

Or as @nicola commented `findInterval` is another option.  The advantage is it is vectorized and can be used to check multiple Threshold values at once.

```
 findInterval(Threshold,cumsum(v))+1
 #[1] 3
 findInterval(c(10,49), cumsum(v))+1
 #[1] 3 7
```